# Twitter Boostrap modal trigger not firing when loaded with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a page with content that gets loaded dynamically via AJAX.  Within that loaded content, I have  tags that act as the trigger to fire a bootstrap modal window.  The problem I have is that when the triggers are loaded after the initial page load, the triggers aren't firing the modal.  When I hard code the  links into the page without AJAX it works fine.  Does anyone know a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your events with delegation. Something like this, with jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.your-trigger-selector', function() {
    // Do stuff, such as opening the modal window.
});
```